# GridView SelectedValue via LinkButton on Select

Tags: c#, asp.net

I usualy just use the default 'Select' on my Data Grids, but now, I need to popup a Modal Popup when the user selects a row. So, I am trying to use an ImageButton:

```
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="../Images/edit.png" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" OnClick="edit_Click" CommandName="Select" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Project Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Code" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access"></asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
```

I created the OnClick event, which fires, and I thought that I can maybe get the selectedvalue of the row in that event. I usually used GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged event.

But I am battling to find a way to get the SelectedValue.

```
protected void edit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
    Session["SelectedUserProjectId"] = ???? // This is where I am trying to get the selected value - but can't find a way to do so.
    var pi = int.Parse(Session["SelectedUserProjectId"].ToString());
    var ui = int.Parse(Session["SelectedUserId"].ToString());
    // Do some calls to get data, populate fields, and then...

    this.pnlEdit_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to get the selected value of the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

in aspx bind you Id in hidden field and Than find that hidden field in code behind and get value

```
  <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="../Images/edit.png" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" OnClick="edit_Click" CommandName="Select" />
<asp:Hiddenfield runat="server" ID="hId" value='<%# Eval("UserProjectId")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Project Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Code" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access"></asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
```

in code behind

```
protected void edit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
    Session["SelectedUserProjectId"] = ((HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("hId")).Value // This is where I am trying to get the selected value - but can't find a way to do so.
    var pi = int.Parse(Session["SelectedUserProjectId"].ToString());
    var ui = int.Parse(Session["SelectedUserId"].ToString());
    // Do some calls to get data, populate fields, and then...

    this.pnlEdit_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Question: `Can anyone guide me on how to get the selected value of the GridView?`

You also need to set the `CommandArgument` property of ImageButton to the Column value you want. Say: `ProjectId`: [ i.e `ProjectId` should be a column in your table ]

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="../Images/edit.png" runat="server" 
 Width="25" Height="25" OnClick="edit_Click" CommandName="Select" 
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectId") %>' />
```

In your `edit_Click` event you can retrieve as:

```
protected void edit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
        Session["SelectedUserProjectId"] = btndetails.CommandArgument;
       // Rest of implementation
    }
```